# Control Flow (Number of Branch)

Tags: cuda

I'm a little bit confused with number of branches.

How do I count number of branch in the following kernel?

My device compute capability is 1.2, kernel configuration is `<<<1,32>>>`
size of data is 32 (I mean one warp.).
The number of branches is  here **6** if I'm not mistaken.. But why is that?

```
__global__ void Kernel(float *c)
{
   int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
   float ia, ib;
   ia = ib = 0.0f;

   if (tid % 2 == 0)
   {
       ia = 100.0f;
   }
   else
   {
       ib = 200.0f;
   }

   c[tid] = ia + ib;
}
```

Comment: It would help us clear up where you went wrong if you were to provide how you arrived at the number 6.

Comment: Hmm, well there are 6 braces. Maybe that's it?

Comment: @RogerDahl    I do not think I went wrong! did you ever check it's reults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless there is something I completely miss here (which I sadly must admit is perfectly likely), I only see 2 code branches here: the `if` branch and the `else` one. Half of the threads of the warp will execute the code of the `if` branch and the second half will execute the `else` branch.

It is true that since the instructions are decoded in lock steps, the code inside these two branches won't execute in parallel within a single warp. Therefor the number of clock cycles for executing the two branches will be the sum of the number of instructions of each branches, not the maximum of the two. But that's the only "trick" here.